# Switching PhD programs for personal reasons

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have recently started a PhD program in the natural sciences (UK). My partner is enrolled in a program at a different university in continental Europe.

The timings of our offers were mismatched, and had they received their offer sooner I would have looked at opportunities in the same place.

I would like to switch programs to the same university my partner is at. I am enjoying my field of study and would like to do nearly the same/something closely related in the other program. This program would be an upgrade in university prestige and come with a substantial pay rise, but probably a side grade from advisor prestige.

The issue I see is how to explain wanting to switch in an application/contact email? Personal reasons must surely be a common reason for changing jobs in general, but how to sell this to a new program? Do I apply without mentioning this and address it if asked in an interview?

Comment: Can you please add the country tag for the country you plan on applying in?

Comment: Procedures for PhD admission in continental Europe can be quite diverse. I recommend to contact the university and department  where you want to go for what your options are. Most should have something like a PhD tutor.